# How to escape dollar and curly braces for replacement operators in Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

Say I have an XML-based template string in which I have to replace self-made template markers:

```
 $template = '<Foo Name="${BAZ}">'
```

I would like to replace the literal `${BAZ}` with a value. I thought using the case-sensitive `-creplace` operator would be a good idea. As givens, I have both the bare parameter name (`BAZ`) without the additional adornment (`${` `}`) and its value (42):

```
 $param = 'BAZ'
 $value = 42
```

So I first derive my replacement string using `-f` to mix the parameter name with its "markup", while carefully escaping the literal `{` and `}` within the format string:

```
 $needle = '${{{0}}}' -f $param 
 # ${BAZ}
 # at least when printed...
```

Now to the final act:

```
 $template -creplace $needle, $value
 # <Foo Name="${BAZ}">
 # so $needle does not seem to match the string '${BAZ}'
```

I seem to have missed (or overcompensated) for some escaping somewhere in between... can somebody pull me off the ice here? (I have tried *many* combinations of backspaces, backticks, single- and double-quoted strings. And just for context: in my real script, `$template` is a large multi-line string via `$template = Get-Content "template-file.xml"`, which I hope is not the root source.)

---

**Edit:** I have found a working solution after some more hunting: by ditching `-creplace` in favour of .net's `Replace()` method, the above `$needle` matches the template:

```
 $template.Replace($needle, $value)
 # <Foo Name="42"/>
```

So I would be glad about any answer that sheds some light on why `-creplace` does not cooperate, what I could do to make it.

Comment: `-creplace` is the case-sensitive version of `-replace`, but it is still an operator that replaces a regex-pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-replace` is an operator that replaces a regular expression.`-creplace` just makes this regular expression case sensitive. The problem you are running into is the regular expression itself, as certain characters have a special role in regex.

What you want to do, is to escape such characters:

```
 $template -replace [regex]::escape($needle), $value
```

The escaped pattern will look like this: `\$\{BAZ}`

Answer (score 2):

In this case `[regex]::escape()` should do the trick.

```
 $template = '<Foo Name="${BAZ}">'
 $template -match [regex]::escape('${BAZ}')
 $Matches
```

Output:

```
Name                           Value 
----                           ----- 
0                              ${BAZ}
```

Comment: Hm... thanks already for this option; I still hope I can go without passing through RegExp territory. After all, I "just" want to replace a string in the most literal sense possible.

Comment: `-replace`, `-match` etc. are `RegEx` operators. If you don't want to use RegEx you should use `$str.Replace()`

Comment: Oh... that coin drop took some more minutes than expected \*blush\*. Thanks in that case for the real correct answer!